# "Functors between monads": what are these really called?

Tags: ct.category-theory, monads

Let $(S,\eta,\mu)$ be a monad on a category $C$, and $(T,\eta,\mu)$ a monad on a category $D$.  The following kind of gadget is ubiquitous: a functor $F:D\to C$, together with a natural map $\sigma: SF\to FT$, satisfying the identities

- $F\eta = \sigma\circ \eta F$,  and
- $\sigma\circ \mu F = F\mu\circ \sigma T\circ S\sigma$.

I might call this a "functor between monads".  **Question:** What do people actually call these, and what are the standard references?

Some random examples:

- $S$ is the free commutative ring monad on abelian groups, $T$ is the free commutative monoid monad on sets, and $F$ is the free abelian group on a set.  (In this case, $\sigma$ is an isomorphism.)
- $S=T=J$, the free associative monoid on pointed spaces (where we force the basepoint to be the unit element), with $F=$ loop space.  (Enriched category theory provides a lot of examples like this.)
- If $F=$ identity functor, we recover the usual notion of morphism between monads.

Some notes:

- A functor between monads as above gives you a way to turn a $T$-algebra into an $S$-algebra, so you obtain a functor $F^*: \mathrm{Alg}_T\to \mathrm{Alg}_S$.
- You can compose "functors between monads", so there is a category with these as morphisms, and monads as the objects.

Comment: +1 for the examples!

Comment: If the forgetful functors for the algebras $S$ and $T$ are fully faithful and $F^*$ is  an equivalence of categories, can we deduce that $F$ is also an equivalence of categories?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As far as I know, the first paper on this was:

> Ross Street, The formal theory of monads.  *Journal of Pure and Applied Algebra* 2 (1972), 149-168.

He called them *monad functors*.  For the same thing but with the direction of the natural transformation reversed, he called them *monad opfunctors*.  You can also consider the case where the natural transformation is an isomorphism, or even the identity, but I forget what he called them.

(If Street's wasn't the first paper on this, it was certainly early and very influential.  And it's a beautiful paper.)

In a bid to try to make the terminology of 2-category theory more systematic, I called them *lax maps of monads* in my book *Higher Operads, Higher Categories* (CUP, 2004), and similarly *colax* etc.  I don't know whether anyone else followed suit.

Recently I examined the thesis of one of Street's students, who I think used different terminology from what's in The formal theory of monads.  I forget what it was, but I'll look it up if I remember.

Comment: viewing monads as _lax_ functors $1 \to \mathbf{Cat}$, then the 1-cells of the lax functor category $Lax(1,\mathbf{Cat})$ are _lax maps of monads_ (guess this was the reason for Tom's choice of terminology); $Lax(1,\mathbf{Cat})$ yields $\mathbf{Mnd}_\mathbf{Cat}$ as defined by Street. [nLab ref for this](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monad#the_bicategory__19) 

Comment: I've used your terminology, Tom.  Another good reason for calling these "lax morphisms of monads" is that there's a 2-monad on Cat whose algebras are "categories equipped with a monad", and whose lax morphisms are these.

Comment: It's a little confusing, though, because what Charles described is a lax morphism of monads *from T to S*, despite the fact that if F is the identity functor, it reduces to what looks like a morphism of some sort *from S to T*.

Answer (score 4):

[Pumplün, D. Eine Bemerkung über Monaden und adjungierte Funktoren.
Math. Ann. 185 (1970). 329-337.](https://eudml.org/doc/161964)
also defines a category of monads.

Comment: On p. 330, defining the natural transformations covariantly. And on p. 334 Pumplün already raises and resolves the issue of whether or not to have them point the other way (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/files/Pumpluen-Monaden.pdf#page=6), as Street makes them do 2 years later...